# Pester 5 mocking and beforediscovery

Tags: powershell, pester-5

trying to test a function in pester 5.3.1 (latest) and ps7.2.1

```
    function Remove-GraphUser
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [object]$cloudUsers
    )
    process
    {
        foreach ($User in $cloudUsers)
        {
            Remove-MgUser -UserId $User.id
            $user
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to mock the remove-mguser function and test the resulting array of user objects output by the function `remove-graphuser`

tried this: but it seems to skip mock defined in beforeall.

```
    BeforeDiscovery {
    $cloud = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\files\cloud.csv
    $result = Remove-GraphUser -cloud $cloud -Verbose
}

Describe 'Remove-GraphUser' -tags 'two' {
    BeforeAll {
        Mock Remove-MgUser {}
    }

    It 'should be called twice' {
        Assert-MockCalled -CommandName Remove-MgUser -Times 2 -Scope describe
    }
    It '<_.id> should be removed from the cloud group' -ForEach $result {
        $_.id | Should -Not -Be $null
    }
}
```

this does not work either(the foreach it block is skipped but assert-mock runs)

```
    BeforeAll {
    Mock Remove-MgUser {}
    $cloud = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\files\umbrella1_cloud.csv
    $result = remove-graphuser -cloud $cloud -Verbose
}
```

Want to be able to mock `remove-mggraphuser` because i dont want to actually remove users just test the logic and also be able to iterate over the `$result` variable using -Foreach.

the `$result` variable contains `pscustomobjects` with `id` and `displayname` properties. I am tsting the function with 2 such objects.

```
 $cloudusers = @([pscustomobject]@{id=1;displayname="john"}, 
   [pscustomobject]@{id=2;displayname="doe"})
```

Update: I think I need to change the way i am testing the data so closing this

Comment: yeah I am just going through trial and error at this point even if things don't make sense. Anyway I am just testing a function which I have dot sourced in another `beforeall` block. There isnt a module at this point.

Comment: thank you for testing...i should have also added the output of the function...so the function outputs pscustomobjects(id and displayname properties). I am testing with 2 such user objects so the `testcases` should iterate over the 2 objects. I am able to get the mock to work in beforeall but the `testcases` wont run because the `$result` var is null which shouldnt be.

Comment: yeah its kind of related to how pester5 phases work and what executes in which phase. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-ForEach is processed during the Discovery-phase, while BeforeAll is processed later during the Run-phase so the solution is to use a foreach loop inside the it block.

```
BeforeDiscovery {
$cloud = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\files\cloud.csv
$result = Remove-GraphUser -cloud $cloud -Verbose
```

}

```
Describe 'Remove-GraphUser' -tags 'two' {
BeforeAll {
    Mock Remove-MgUser {}
}

It 'should be called twice' {
    Assert-MockCalled -CommandName Remove-MgUser -Times 2 -Scope describe
}
It user should be removed from the cloud group' -ForEach $result {
   foreach ($index in $result)
    {
        $index.id | Should -Not -Be $null
        $index.ad_id | Should -Be $null
    }

}
}
```